# Node.js module to retrieve a file from a server, convert format and pass it to main Node.js application

Tags: node.js, server, converters

Sorry if this is really basic, but I'm fairly new to Node. I'm looking to retrieve a CSV file from a server as standard input using a Node.js module that will pass said file on to a larger Node application after converting it into a JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the aptly named  [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) . Getting the file from the server should not pose a problem for you, and depending on your flow you either let your main application call the conversion, or subscribe to conversions indirectly.